# How can I prevent the browser from scrolling on top of the page when clicking the checkbox?

Tags: html, css

Whenever I click on the checkbox, the browser window (firefox) will scroll on the top of the screen.
How can I prevent this behavior so when I click on the checkbox the browser window will not scroll on top?
Here is the code found from here http://jsfiddle.net/zAFND/6/
Thank you.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <style>
            div label input {
                margin-right: 100px;
            }

            body {
                font-family:sans-serif;
            }

            #ck-button {
                margin: 4px;
                background-color: #EFEFEF;
                border-radius: 4px;
                border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
                overflow: auto;
                float: left;
            }

            #ck-button {
                margin: 4px;
                background-color: #EFEFEF;
                border-radius: 4px;
                border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
                overflow: auto;
                float: left;
            }

            #ck-button:hover {
                margin: 4px;
                background-color: #EFEFEF;
                border-radius: 4px;
                border: 1px solid red;
                overflow: auto;
                float: left;
                color: red;
            }

            #ck-button label {
                float: left;
                width: 4.0em;
            }

            #ck-button label span {
                text-align: center;
                padding: 3px 0px;
                display: block;
            }

            #ck-button label input {
                position: absolute;
                top: -20px;
            }

            #ck-button input:checked + span {
                background-color: #911;
                color: #fff;
            }
        </style>    
</head>
    <body>
        <br>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <div id="ck-button">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="1"><span>red</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The problem is this rule:

```
#ck-button label input {
  position:absolute;
  top:-20px;
}
```

When you click on a label the browser tries to focus the related input. In your case the checkbox element is lying *at the top* of the page, even outside the viewport – so Firefox tries to scroll there.

You can solve it like this by adding:

```
#ck-button label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/auULh/)

**Alternative**

Heisenberg points out a problem in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18764858/1456376) which can occur when using extreme values. Unfortunately the proposed idea has the same quirk as the one shown above.

So an alternative solution is simply to hide the input. The functionality is not affected.

**CSS**

```
#ck-button label input {
  display: none;
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/70cy9os3/)

Comment: I found your answer because I was using a star rating widget that used -9999 for the position of its radio buttons. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! For the explanation and the solution!

Comment: Good CSS practice: don't use `position: absolute` unless necessary.

Comment: `display: none;` great solution, many thanks

Answer (score 21):

The answer accepted is not entirely true. Works, but not in all cases.

If you use the common css to hide elements (probably  -999em or similar) at the "top" attribute, in this case **position:relative has nothing to do because always -999em will be much higher than the viewport**.

The answer accepted works fine because the "top" is only -20px . Try to set it a more higher number and you´ll see the problem.

So, **the solution is not to set a relative position**.
I think the correct way is only to **set a negative value at left position** (not top).

Try it. :)

Comment: Indeed this works. the accepted answer added top padding and this one resolved this, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out a problem in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17974351/1456376). I've updated it accordingly. Also your solution is another possibility, it has the same quirk as mine. Try to set the value for `left` very high, like: `#ck-button label input { position:absolute; left:-10000px; }`. You can see it in this [demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rnxaf4ve/). You will not be able to click the button in Webkit-Browsers (Chrome and Safari) and it also doesn't work in Firefox as required.

Answer (score 7):

you could hide your checkbox input like this:

```
#ck-button label input {
    position:absolute;
    top:+20px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```