# How to prevent page jumps when checkbox's state changes?

Tags: html, css, checkbox, radio-button

[Example page](http://jsfiddle.net/IanY/pabnzoar/1/).

When you scroll down the page until you can only see a little portion of the `label` (lightgreen/lightblue vertical rectangle), then click on the `label` to change the state of the checkbox. You then see the page jumps up in order to show the whole `label`.

How to prevent the jump from happening? I know setting CSS `display: none` on the `input` works, but that also hides the `input` from screen readers and is bad for Accessibility.

Comment: It's by design. If you click via label, it will be scrolled to let label visible.

Comment: @Raptor, it is to let `input` visible, not `label`. When `input` is set `display: none`, the jump is not happening.

Comment: @IanY. I think you answer is right. Or visibility:hidden.

Comment: See this. Use visibility, the element will still in document.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17974351/4436090

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this. Use visibility, the element will still in document.

> [How can I prevent the browser from scrolling on top of the page when clicking the checkbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17974351/4436090)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I just want to provide the right answer.  But this answer can't be deleted since it's already accepted, what should I do now?

Answer (score 3):

Totaly understand your concerns but I think it can be done with display:none - with help of aria-label or alternatives.

This is good for accessibility (and SEO too, as I understand robot logic):

> *The aria-label attribute is used to define a string that labels the current element. Use it in cases where a text label is not visible on
>   the screen. (If there is visible text labeling the element, use
>   aria-labelledby instead.)*

src: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-label_attribute

So - your fiddle (html only):

```
<div>
    <input  aria-label="test" id="test" type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fbogny68/

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to keep `label`?

Comment: Note that ARIA is supported in modern browsers only: http://caniuse.com/#feat=wai-aria