# How can I display two results in a JavaScript calculator?

Tags: javascript, calculator

I am building this little calculator where there is only one input field and when user submits the data, I want form to do 2 calculations and display the results in separate divs.

In the first div, I want to whatever user puts in the input area and multiply it by 0.017 (result goes into first div). For the second calculation, I want to multiply the whatever value was put into the input field by 0.170 and display the result in a separate div. Please see the image for visual rep.

[image]

Comment: Post your code in your question please.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! You will have best results with your question if you show your current code, you will get really good results with js/html questions by using a tool such as http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I had copied a generic js script and tried to modify it but did not work. Here is JS fiddle for HTML and CSS. After selecting the input area, how can I perform two calculations and display them separately? Your help is much appreciated. http://jsfiddle.net/nmbwamtd/

Comment: Was my question not appropriate for this site? As you can see I am not very competent when it comes to coding but I must figure this stuff out asap. So if anyone does help, I would appreciate it.

Comment: I added my script: http://jsfiddle.net/nmbwamtd/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially you are creating two values (one calculation for each field) then setting the inside of the display elements (the DIVs) to the values of the calculations:

```
var someNumber = 10;
var someNumberAfterCalculationOne = someNumber % 4;
var someNumberAfterCalculationTwo = someNumber - someNumberAfterCalculationOne;

document.getElementById("lt_input").innerHTML = someNumberAfterCalculationOne;
document.getElementById("kg_input").innerHTML = someNumberAfterCalculationTwo;
```

Here is an example of how you might accomplish this:

http://jsfiddle.net/nmbwamtd/3/

This approach is a little ugly, but should get you through to the next step.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I see you set a variable for someNumber. I want to grab and use the number which user puts into the area_input. How can I revise your code to do that. Basically, whatever the number inside the area_input, I´d like to do two calculations and display them in lt_input and kg_input divs. ???

Comment: Sure! you grab the value similarly to how you set it in the div (a little different since it's not a DIV but an INPUT) and then validate that it is a number: http://jsfiddle.net/nmbwamtd/4/

Comment: Thanks you so much. It works great in JS fiddle, when I put the code into my editor, it resets the input value and returns to top of the page. I have revised the numbers as below:     

var someNumberAfterCalculationOne = area * 0,170;
var someNumberAfterCalculationTwo = area * 0,0170;

Comment: Sorry, not sure I can help you with your editor - this might help you with the scrolling to the top of the page issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17974108/how-can-i-prevent-the-browser-from-scrolling-on-top-of-the-page-when-clicking-th. If this has answered the question you posed, please remember to check the checkbox to accept it, thx!