# Disable Android Scrolls on checkbox click

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I am developing a website that uses a large number of checkboxes.  We have had complaints from our clients with android phones that when they click on the checkboxs that the phone scrolls the checkbox to the top of the screen.  We have tried many things including the code below without any success in removing the scroll.

We are looking for any code that could prevent this from occurring. Thanks in advance.

```
e.stopPropagation();
e.preventDefaults();
```

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a clear example? In jsfiddle?

Comment: I cannot reproduce it on my side.. I think there're some problems with your CSS maybe. Can you provide an example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I prevent the browser from scrolling on top of the page when clicking the checkbox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17974108/how-can-i-prevent-the-browser-from-scrolling-on-top-of-the-page-when-clicking-th)

Comment: I believe this is distinct from the possible duplicate mentioned above. I see this on Android with rich text editing.